# Remove files excluding files-list in file in shell - delete files from one directory that don't also exist in another

Tags: bash, file, shell, diff

I have file with files:

```
./aaa
./bbb
./c/ccc
./d/ddd
```

I have another directory with the same files and some another ones.

```
./aaa
./bbb
./c/ccc
./d/ddd
./to-remove-1
./c/to-rem-ove-2
```

I need to remove all files that are not in the first list.

P.S. Actually the first list has been made by command `find /some/dir/ -type f > somefile`. So we have another dir. But I'm looking working with a file.

Comment: cant you just read each line of the file into a variable, then compare these with the `awk` command to get the file names, to the files in the current directory and if the file isnt one of the variables delete the file?

Comment: @jgr208 that doesn't exactly sound straightforward... Can't you *just* post an answer showing how what you're describing is done?

Comment: @arco444 i had no code so it would only be an algorithm really, which is normally not what people are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**On Linux (using GNU utilities)**

```
cd "/other/dir/"
# Consider using -xtype f to also include *symlinks* to files.
find . -type f -print0 |
  grep -Fxvz -f <(cd "/some/dir" && find . -type f) |
    xargs -0 echo rm
```

**On BSD/OSX**

```
cd "/other/dir/"
find . -type f |
  grep -Fxv -f <(cd "/some/dir" && find . -type f) |
    tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 echo rm
```

**POSIX-compliant variant - *slower***

```
cd "/other/dir/"
find . -type f |
 grep -Fxv -f <(cd "/some/dir" && find . -type f) |
   xargs -I {} echo rm {}
```

<sup>The above solutions perform a dry run; remove `echo` to perform actual deletion.

Also, instead of using static file `someFile` as `-f someFile` in the `grep` command, a process substitution that creates the reference file list on the fly is used: `-f <(cd "/some/dir" && find . -type f)`; `bash`, not `sh`, is required to make this work.

Note that `type -f` matches only *regular* files, and not *symlinks* to files. GNU Find offers `-xtype -f` to also match the latter.</sup>

- `find . -type f` lists all (regular) files in the subtree of the current directory;
  on Linux, `-print0` outputs each path terminated with a NUL (a zero byte, `0x0`) rather than a newline.
- `grep -Fxv` excludes (`-v`) all input lines that literally (`-F`) and exactly (`-x`) match a line in the output from the [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) that creates the reference file list (`-f <(...)`) - in other words: it outputs only those input lines that do not exist in reference list.
  On Linux, the additional `-z` (`--null-data`) option breaks the input into records by NUL bytes rather than newlines - given that the input is NUL-separated.
- `xargs ... rm` converts the input paths passed via stdin into command-line arguments to pass to `rm`.

  - In the Linux and BSD solutions this will typically result in only *one* `rm` invocation (as many paths as will fit on a single command line are passed to `rm`), to which *all* input paths passed as arguments.
  - In the POSIX solution, `rm` must be called *once per path*.

---

- Handling of **embedded whitespace in paths**: <sup>tip of the hat to [@user000001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828193/user000001) for his input</sup>

  - The Linux solution can ***in principle* handle *all* whitespace embedded in paths**, notably including *newlines*, which, while quite rare, is possible.

    - It achieves this by passing NUL-separated paths through the pipeline from start to finish.
    - That said, ***in the case at hand*, embedded newlines are NOT supported**, because the reference list passed to Grep's `-f` *must* be *line-based* to work as expected. Even with option `--null-data` present, GNU Grep requires that the search terms in the file passed to `-f` be *newline*-separated - NUL separation doesn't work.
  - The **BSD and POSIX solutions can *fundamentally* only handle embedded *spaces and tabs***.

    - The BSD solution uses `tr '\n' '\0'` to replace all newlines with NULs, which, combined with `xargs -0` preserves each input line as its own argument when `xargs` invokes `rm`.

      - Caveat: BSD Grep *also* has a `-z` option, but its purpose is very different. BSD Grep has *no* equivalent to GNU Grep's `-z` (`--null-data`) option, and using the latter is the only way to preserve *embedded* newlines in the input.
    - The POSIX solution uses `xargs -I {} rm {}` to treat each input line as a *single* argument to pass to `rm` - the downside is that `rm` must then be called *once for every line (path)*.
      Using POSIX-only features, you cannot pass *multiple* arguments with embedded spaces or tabs at once, except if you surround each token with quotes, but that comes with its own challenges.

Comment: If the purpose of ` ... | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ...` is to protect from newlines in the filenames, it doesn't. You would have to use GNU grep's [`--null`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Output-Line-Prefix-Control)  and [`--null-data`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Other-Options) options (or their corresponding options depending on your grep version).

Comment: @user000001: Thanks; no, the intent was solely to help with embedded _spaces_, but since I originally said "whitespace", I can see why one would think that - I've changed the wording and added a warning re embedded _newlines_.

Comment: You are right, `--null` is not relevant, but `--null-data` does what you want, provided that you add `-print0` to the find command. Re the filenames with newlines, I got hit once when I copied the titles of some papers from the pdfs to their filenames, without realizing that the newlines were also copied. It's rare, but rare things do happen sometimes...

Comment: @user000001: Excellent point re `--null-data` in combination with `find -print0`; the caveat
is that `--null-data` is a _GNU_ Grep extension (BSD Grep doesn't support it). Using this combination is a good idea in general, but, as I've just discovered, won't actually help in this case,
because the search terms passed via `-f` must still be _line-based_, even when using `--null-data`. Thus, embedded-newline paths in the _reference list_ aren't supported. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: You know this construction: `grep -Fxv -f <(cd "/some/dir" && find . -type f)` doesn't work on CentOS 6.5.

`rm-files-except-list.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token '('
rm-files-except-list.sh: line 13:   grep -Fxvz -f <(cd "$httpDir" && find . -type f) '|'`

Comment: @Kirby: That suggests you're not using `bash` to run the script, which, however,  is required to support the [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) (`<(...)`). If you can't use `bash`, send command output to a temp. file first and use the filename with `-f` (as in your question).

Comment: Hm, I have shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash`. But yes, it was run with `sh some.sh`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Short Answer

The directories to be compared are `A` and `B`, with the "extra" files being removed from `B`:

```
$ (cd A && find .) > tmp.txt
$ cd B && find . >> ../tmp.txt
$ sort ../tmp.txt | uniq -u | xargs rm
$ rm ../tmp.txt
```

#### One liner

```
$ (cd B && { (cd ../A && find .) && (find .) } | sort | uniq -u | xargs rm)
```

This avoids the use of a temp file using command grouping. Note that this won't work if you have filenames with spaces in them. See "Caveats" below.

## Explanation

#### Using `uniq`, `find`, `sort`, and `xargs`.

`uniq -u` will remove all duplicated lines from a file. For example, we can reduce your directory structure to the following, using `find` and `sort`:

```
.
.
./c
./c
./c/ccc
./c/ccc
./c/to-rem-ove-2
./d
./d
./d/ddd
./d/ddd
./to-remove-1
```

With this in hand, `uniq -u` gives us:

```
./c/to-rem-ove-2
./to-remove-1
```

You can pipe this into `xargs` and use `rm` to remove the files. e.g. `... | uniq -u | xargs rm`.

#### A step-by-step breakdown

1. We have the following directory structure:

   ```
   $ tree .
   .
   ├── A
   │   ├── c
   │   │   └── ccc
   │   └── d
   │       └── ddd
   └── B
       ├── c
       │   ├── ccc
       │   └── to-rem-ove-2
       ├── d
       │   └── ddd
       └── to-remove-1
   ```
2. We can list all of directories with the `find` command.

   ```
   $ find .
   .
   ./B
   ./B/to-remove-1
   ./B/c
   ./B/c/ccc
   ./B/c/to-rem-ove-2
   ./B/d
   ./B/d/ddd
   ./A
   ./A/c
   ./A/c/ccc
   ./A/d
   ./A/d/ddd
   ```

   We don't want to have the leading directories for `uniq`, so we'll
   `cd` into each directory before running `find`, and save the list of all files to a temp file, `tmp.txt`.

   ```
   $ (cd A && find .) > tmp.txt
   $ (cd B && find .) >> tmp.txt
   ```
3. Since `uniq -u` operates on sorted files (duplicate lines must
   appear next to each other), we must sort `tmp.txt` using `sort`.

   ```
   $ sort tmp.txt | uniq -u
   ./c/to-rem-ove-2
   ./to-remove-1
   ```
4. We can now use `xargs` to remove the "extra" files from `B`.

   ```
   $ cd B
   $ sort ../tmp.txt | uniq -u | xargs rm
   ```

   The files are now gone:

   ```
   $ find .
   .
   ./c
   ./c/ccc
   ./d
   ./d/ddd
   ```

## Caveats

1. Per [mklement0's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330029/remove-files-excluding-files-list-in-file-in-shell/30331377?noredirect=1#comment48761319_30331377), you can use `xargs -I {} rm {}`
   instead of plain `xargs rm` to make sure that the command doesn't do
   the wrong thing if there are spaces in filenames.
2. Using, again, "vanilla" `xargs rm` won't delete directories, even
   though they are listed in the `find` command's output. If you had a
   directory `e` under `B` that wasn't in `A` (and should therefore be
   deleted), you would receive an error like

   ```
   rm: cannot remove ‘./e’: Is a directory
   ```

   If you would wanted to keep these directories, you could ignore the
   error. If you needed to delete them, you could use `rm -r` in place
   of `rm`. If you are doing this, it's probably best to combine it with `sort -r` so that the files within a directory are deleted before the directory, if necessary. It doesn't change the functionality if you don't make this change, but there might be "errors" posted when there shouldn't be.

The whole command with all of these changes is

```
(cd B && { (cd ../A && find .) && (find .) } | 
 sort -r | uniq -u | xargs -I {} rm -r {})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2) -13 | xargs -r rm
```

Comment: This would make for a great answer, if you (a) showed how to plug in the `find` commands, (b) made the `xargs` command deal properly with paths with embedded spaces, (c) fixed the `rm` command to deal with warnings / prompts resulting from deleting directories before their children, and (d) explained how everything works. P.S.: (e) for the  `comm` command to be portable, options `-13` must go _before_ the operands.